# .htaccess rewrite single page url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a problem with mod_rewrite.
In my .htaccess i have some rules that works correctly, but when i try to rewrite a single page the server return a 404 error.
For example

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
...other ruler that works....
RewriteRule "^page/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$" "/myPage.php?id=$2" [L]
RewriteRule "^pageTwo/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$" "/myPagetwo.php?id=$2" [L]
RewriteRule "^page3/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)$" "/myPagetwo.php?id=$2" [L]   
#error rule
RewriteRule "^singlePage$" "/page.php" [L]
</IfModule>
```

The only last rule don't work, if i check www.mysite.com/singlePage i get a 404 error.

Comment: does "page.php" file exist on your server?

Comment: yes, if i write www.mystie.com/page.php works

Comment: add a NC flag to your last rule **[NC,L]** .

Comment: Nothing, with RewriteRule "^singlePage$" "/page.php" [NC, L] return the same 404 error

Comment: L means last, NC next condition. so they are totally irrelevant your rule was correct in first place. Make sure you have /page.php. in where the document root is in virtualhost definition. you are missing php file.

Comment: Ah. i couldn't notice. you have already set the RewriteBase, so you don't need to use "/" in file path. change your rule to this. RewriteRule ^singlePage$ page.php [L]  without double quotes.

Comment: @Risyasin NC means No Case ,not Next Condition. it is used for ignoring case insensitivity in RewritePattern otherwisie without this flag apache will return 404 error if Request uri has uppercase letters.

Comment: @Starkeen yes you're right. i have confused it with "N" which is next condition. Thank you for correcting.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule ^ singlePage/?$ page.php [L]
```

Flag at the end tells Apache server how to apply the rule. "L" tells not to process any more rules if this one is used.